# Is there a reason why the identity of Hush was retconned in the animated movie Batman: Hush?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-movie-universe, batman-hush

In the 2019 animated movie *Batman: Hush*, the main antagonist, Hush is revealed to be none other than

> The Riddler.

However, this is a complete deviation from the comics where the character of Hush was Bruce's childhood friend **Dr. Thomas Elliot**.

Although the key plot points of the story in the film coincides with the 12-issue storyline *Batman: Hush* (by Loeb and Lee) such as:

> 1. The Riddler was diagnosed with terminal cancer and uses one of the Lazarus Pits to cure himself. 
>  
>  
>  2. Due to his exposure to the mystical properties of the Lazarus pit, he deduces that Bruce Wayne is Batman.

The major plot change was the reveal of the person behind the mask of Hush.

Is there an explanation provided by the writers (of the movie or the comics) as to why this drastic change was introduced in the movie?

Answer (score 5):

Interview with Screewriter Ernie Altbacker:

[Batman Hush Uses Red Herrings To Fake Out Fans - SDCC 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYilEMxSq0s)

The reason is two-fold:

1. Time constraints of condensing a 12-part mini-series into 70 minutes
2. Faking Out the audience to keep a familiar story fresh

The original story had a lot of red-herrings.  Going with one of them as the actual new ending instead of a dead-end, allowed them to condense the story and surprise the audience.